# Bazel: Can the output of one extra_action be used as input of a succeeding extra_action?

Tags: bazel, bazel-extra-action

I use two succeeding extra_action in the Bazel build. I wonder if there is a way to specify that the output files generated by the first extra_action shall be used as input to another extra_action (both executes during the same build)?

I use bazel extra_action to execute a lint-tool while bazel is compiling.
That works good. For each lint of a source code file the lint tool will generate a special output: *.lob.
Then I would like to execute the tool once again during a succeeding action. The link step could be one choice since all compiling is ready then (but if someone knows other actions to use I am grateful if you could share). This time all .lob files are linted together to make sure they are consistent with one another.
I wonder if there is a way to specify that the output of the first extra_action shall be an input to another extra_action (both executes during the same build)?

Comment: Maybe Aspects are more suitable for this? https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
I will look into that.